# segmentation fault 11 when using assignment and printf

Tags: c

I am getting a segmentation fault 11 error on the print statement in the while(splitting) loop. If I comment out the assignment statement the printf statement executes perfectly, But if I don't, the print statement won't work and will tell me the index is out of bounds. With the assignment statement under it, the print statement won't even execute on the 4th iteration, unless I comment out the assignment statement. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    char* filename = argv[1];
    FILE* file = fopen(filename, "r");
    int features = atoi(argv[2]);
    int examples = atoi(argv[3]);
    printf("Filename: %s\n", filename);
    printf("Features: %d\n", features);
    printf("Training examples: %d\n", examples);
    int **X = malloc(examples * sizeof(int));
    for(int i = 0; i < examples; i++){
        X[i] = malloc(features * sizeof(int));
    }
    int lineLength = (2 * features) + 1;
    char *example = malloc(lineLength * sizeof(char)); 
    char *splitting = malloc(lineLength * sizeof(char));
    int exampleNumber = 0;
    int featureNumber;
    while(fgets(example, lineLength, file)){
        printf("%d: ", exampleNumber);
        printf("%s\n", example);
        splitting = strtok(example, ",");
        featureNumber = 0;
        while(splitting){
            printf("%d,%d ", exampleNumber, featureNumber);
            X[exampleNumber][featureNumber] = atoi(splitting);
            splitting = strtok(NULL, ",");
            featureNumber++;
        }
        printf("\n");
        exampleNumber++;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < examples; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < features; j++){
            printf("%d,", X[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: It's not likely crashing on the print statement. It's just that stdout doesn't get flushed until after the program crashes (likely on the subsequent line).  Change your printf statement to include an end-of-line character.  `printf("%d,%d\n", exampleNumber, featureNumber);`

Comment: I agree, Pretty sure the seg fault is happening on the line after printf.

Comment: Is it possible the file it's processing has data that exceeds the example/feature dimensions? You should detect this and error out.

Comment: 1) You should check the value of `argc` 2) You should check the return value of `fopen`, `malloc` etc 3) See @RSahu's answer 4) Use `calloc` instead of `malloc`, especially for `X[i]`. 5) `free` the allocated memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing I noticed is that you are using the wrong size in first call to `malloc`.

```
int **X = malloc(examples * sizeof(int));
                                   ^^^^^
```

It needs to be `sizeof(int*)`, or `sizeof(*X)`.

**PS** That might not solve everything.

Comment: I feel he should use `calloc` as he's allocating for an array, which makes his intention clearer. Also `X` should be lowercase ;)

Comment: I was about to answer this question the same as R Sahu. If this is 64-bit, that's the likely problem.  sizeof(pointer) will be 8 whereas sizeof(int) will be 4.

Comment: @Dai, what's the relationship between `calloc` and allocating for an array?

Comment: @RSahu `calloc` implies "allocating for an array" (given the names of its parameters), and it also preemptively zeroes-memory, which can be safer (and if it's an array of pointers, makes it easy to see which elements are set or not).

Comment: @Dai, thanks for the clarification. The most interesting part of `calloc` is that the returned memory is correctly aligned for the object size. You don't get that when using `malloc`.

Comment: @crypt3c, because you need `examples` number of pointers, each of which points to `example` number of `int`s.